# JSON Configuration in full .NET Framework Console App

Tags: c#, .net, json, configuration, asp-net-config-builders

I have a Console App targeting .NET 4.7.1. I'm trying to use .net core like configuration in my .Net Framework app. My `App.config is:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="configBuilders" type="System.Configuration.ConfigurationBuildersSection, System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" restartOnExternalChanges="false" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <configBuilders>
    <builders>
    <add name="SimpleJson"
         jsonFile="config.json"
         optional="false"
         jsonMode="Sectional"
         type="Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.SimpleJsonConfigBuilder, Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Json, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" /></builders>
  </configBuilders>
```

And I have a file `config.json` which has property "Copy Always" set to `True`. `config.json` looks like:

```
  {
  "appSettings": {
    "setting1": "value1",
    "setting2": "value2",
    "complex": {
      "setting1": "complex:value1",
      "setting2": "complex:value2"
    }
  },

  "connectionStrings": {
    "mySpecialConnectionString": "Dont_check_connection_information_into_source_control"
  }
}
```

Then, in my `main` method, I try to read a config value like:

```
var config = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings
```

However, the value of `config` is always null. I tried the following:

1. Tried changing `jsonFile` to `~/config.json`;
2. Tried giving a very basic key-value (flat) json config while setting `jsonMode` to default value of flat;

But, can't get the config to work. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 16):

If you want to use config json files as in .Net Core, you can install NuGet packages [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration/) and [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json/)
and then initialize the configuration

```
IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
.AddJsonFile("config.json", optional: true)
.Build();
```

After this you can use configuration as in .Net Core. For example:

```
{
  "myConfig": {
    "item1": "config options"
  }
}
```

For this json you will call:

```
var configItem = configuration["myConfig:item1"];
```

Comment: But these 2 nuget packages depends on .netCore 3.1 will they work for .net framework 4.6 apps?

Comment: For Net Framework you must use version 1.1.2 since newer versions do not support Net Framework: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json/1.1.2

Comment: Since you need to use a deprecated version of the Microsoft extensions, it probably means that this approach is not fully supported in .NET Framework by Microsoft anymore. Since the OP specifically asked for a .NET Framework solution, I down-voted this answer.

Comment: I understand you are trying to evolve away from the app.config configuration and you have valid reasons to do that but I would say @JimK is right: the recommended way for .NET Framework projects is, as you had before, via Settings (app.config) which is an autogenerated type-safe class after you configure the settings in the project using the settings designer.  It is quite trivial to work with and, more importantly, type-safe; something appsettings.json is not out of the box, i.e., you need to somehow parse it yourself.

Comment: You can use version 7 of these packages with Framework 4.6.2+. So this approach is now fully supported in .NET Framework.

Answer (score 4):

I did this as well some time ago but it was not just an one-liner. You can use the Microsoft Nuget Packages  `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` & `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json` and setup up your own ConfigurationBuilder.

Take a look at [this article](http://benfoster.io/blog/net-core-configuration-legacy-projects), I think you should get through with it.

Comment: I think that the whole idea is to use SimpleJsonConfigBuilder from [MicrosoftConfigurationBuilders](https://github.com/aspnet/MicrosoftConfigurationBuilders) but it seems it is not just "take it from the box". There is no test yet in this project for this case. There is SimpleJson_GetValue() and SimpleJson_GetAllValues() but both are empty.

Comment: For Net Framework you must use version 1.1.2 since newer versions do not support Net Framework: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json/1.1.2

Answer (score 1):

- The main thing I see omitted from your question is specifying the "configBuilders" attribute in your web.config file's "appSettings" element:**`<appSettings configBuilders="SimpleJson">`**
- I do not think you have to remove the jsonMode="Sectional" attribute.
- I do not think you have to configure set "Copy Always" to True for
  config.json.

This is the code that works for me:

```
<configBuilders>
    <builders>
    <add name="SimpleJson" jsonFile="~\developer_config.json" optional="false" jsonMode="Sectional" type="Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.SimpleJsonConfigBuilder, Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Json, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" />
    </builders>
</configBuilders>
<appSettings configBuilders="SimpleJson">
...
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the example in [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/MicrosoftConfigurationBuilders/blob/master/samples/SampleWebApp/Web.config)

You should add in your config file section

```
<appSettings configBuilders="SimpleJson">
<add key="AppConfiguration:Key1" value="will be replaced by value in json file" />
</appSettings>
```

And remove  jsonMode="Sectional" attribute.

You can access your value using

```
var key1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppConfiguration:Key1"];
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure how are the defaults working right now, but i'll show you how i loaded my config files in .net core.

After CreateDefaultBuilder and before UseStartup add ConfigureAppConfiguration method like that:

```
 public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
                {
                    //HostingEnvironment = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;

                    //config.SetBasePath(HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath);
                    var workingDirectory = AppContext.BaseDirectory; // HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath // Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
                    foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(workingDirectory, "*_config.json"))
                    {
                        config.AddJsonFile(file);//);Path.GetFileName(file));
                    }
                })
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

In your case, if your config is not loaded:

```
config.AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(workingDirectory, "config.json"));
```

This adds .config file to the applicication.
In ConfigureServices method we can access this configurations by sections and fill some class properties with this values.

```
services.Configure<CommonAppSettings>(this.Configuration.GetSection("appSettings"));
```

Direct access:

```
var value1 = this.Configuration.GetSection("appSettings").GetValue(typeof(string), "setting1", "defaultValueIfNotFound");
```

Connection string:

```
//I'm not sure about "ConnectionStrings" section case sensitivity.
var connectionString = this.Configuration.GetConnectionString("mySpecialConnectionString");
```

Helpful link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1