# How to read data from a file which contains data in JSON syntax and store requird keys and values as a variable

Tags: c#, config

I have to say this is not a perfect world stackoverflow problem where I'm stuck with a code level problem But I want to know how I can full fill the following requirement. Any Suggestion/advice would be great

I have a main folder , which contains many sub-folders . Each of these subfolders are expected to have a FieServer.config file which has data in JSON format as shown in the code below.

```
{
  "name": "Max",
  "age": "six",
  "gender": "Male",
  "country": "india",
}
```

I want to know how I can Read from the file and store the 2 keys  "Name" and "Country" along with its respective values as variables to be used in my C# project.

Any suggestions for the above requirement

Comment: You can first read the FieServer.config file as string and then use the Newtonsoft.Json library to read/deserialize the json string.

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeWithJsonSerializerFromFile.htm

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JObjectProperties.htm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I parse JSON with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c)

Comment: What is a your C# project type? There's a lot of helper methods to work with configuration depending on the project type.

Comment: @swdon this is actually a WPF project

Comment: Answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53605249/json-configuration-in-full-net-framework-console-app/53609598) look feasible.

Answer (score 0):

you can see this web
[How to read and write a JSON file in C#](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/525ff8f2-13f5-4602-bce3-78b909cadedb/how-to-read-and-write-a-json-file-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral)

Answer (score 0):

Your best option will be to first prepare an object to be used for the data. i.e.

```
public class FileConfigData 
{ 
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Country {get; set; }
}
```

Then just use any json serializer to transform the JSON to an object.
Here's an example with json.Net lib:
var configData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(File.ReadAllText(CONFIG_FILE_PATH)));

To get all the files into a array you can use:

```
string[] fileConfigs = Directory.GetFiles("path/to/dir", "FieServer.config", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

and then iterate the array like this:

```
List<FileConfigData> configList = new List<FileConfigData>();
foreach (var file in fileConfigs){
   var configData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FileConfigData>(File.ReadAllText(CONFIG_FILE_PATH)));
configList.Add(configData);
 }
```

I advise you also to check the links @Willseed and @Marc posted as well as https://stackoverflow.com/a/12332495/2483016